# MonoTouch + MonoDroid: Can project files live in same folder?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I have a `common C# code base` to share with MonoTouch (iOS) and MonoDroid (Android)

Can I / should I, place the `common.android.csproj` and the `common.iOS.csproj` in the same folder? Both will want to make bin folders and the like and may be problematic?

Like this?:

[image: Folder with 2 csproj]

Comment: I've quite a few of my projects this way, I do not have any problems.

Comment: If you have /bin folder problems, you can change the output path in the project properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You absolutely can.

Further I think it's excellent good practice for shared code where every single file is shared between the two project files - it's what I do in cases like:

https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.Core

---

For cases where the project contents are subtly different - e.g. where one project contains some android specific files, then I prefer the approach of using separate folders and linking the files across. This is an approach I've seen used in lots of Windows projects - e.g. see the source tree of [mvvmlight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a9071d84ec65) - where GalaSoft.MvvmLight (NET35) is the main folder and the other folders all link to its contents plus add their own specific files.

[image: mvvmlight structure]

---

In the next few weeks, there's also hopefully some portable library support coming for shared code in monodevelop.

When that hits, I'm intending to shift to using portable libraries for Touch and Droid - at which point I won't need shared project files at all.